# Strip/delete all values from MySQL query using PHP regex?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, strip

How to strip/delete all values from MySQL queries using PHP Regex?

Example:

original: `SELECT id, abc FROM mytable WHERE id IN (12, 15)`
striped: `SELECT id, abc FROM mytable WHERE id IN ()`

original:

```
SELECT ut.id, IF(stagiaire_devis.id IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(ut.prenom, ' (my lovely)', ut.prenom) AS value FROM quality AS uq, avocate, utility AS ut LEFT JOIN stagiaire_devis ON (stagiaire_devis.id_devis='1293049' AND stagiaire_devis.id_utilisateur=ut.id) WHERE uq.id_utilisateur = ut.id AND avocate.id_utilisateur = ut.id AND avocate.deleted = 0 AND avocate.id_avocat_liste_cabinet = 7 AND uq.id_liste_qualite IN (5,2,9) AND uq.actif = 2 ORDER BY ut.prenom
```

striped:

```
SELECT ut.id, IF(stagiaire_devis.id IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(ut.prenom, '', ut.prenom) AS value FROM quality AS uq, avocate, utility AS ut LEFT JOIN stagiaire_devis ON (stagiaire_devis.id_devis='' AND stagiaire_devis.id_utilisateur=ut.id) WHERE uq.id_utilisateur = ut.id AND avocate.id_utilisateur = ut.id AND avocate.deleted = AND avocate.id_avocat_liste_cabinet = AND uq.id_liste_qualite IN () AND uq.actif = ORDER BY ut.prenom
```

I cannot find right regex :(

Comment: I would believe it to be hard to find a Regex for this. Essentially you have to parse the SQL, detect whether a text is a "value" or not, and then remove it. It might be a better approach to tell us what you really need, because a query without values does not really make sense to me.

Comment: I need to remove all values from SQL query, so there will be only sql command, field, and table in SQL query

Comment: We can tell what will be left after you remove literal values.  That doesn't answer the question of *why* you're doing it.  If you describe what you're going to do with an SQL statement that has its values stripped, maybe we can suggest some other way to do that.

Comment: I need to strip all values from this sql queries so i can have general sql query in purpose to have a look into sql error log on same error queries and i need to ignore the value inside the queries so its like grouping sql error messages

Comment: I'm trying with PHP-SQL-PARSER by parsing and creator but cannot find the solution to recognize the value and strip out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with any regex because SQL is not a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

To do this task, you need to use an [SQL parser](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql%20parser).

---

Edit regarding your comment:

Okay, you need to establish a kind of 'fingerprint' for the query so that you can group queries together when they differ only in constant values.

The [pt-query-digest](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-query-digest.html) tool can do this.  It works with the slow-query log or the general log, but not the error log.  But it's probably not hard to use `awk` or something to convert your error log into a format that pt-query-digest can read.